# Swap player every two turns JavaScript - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a score keeping game using AngularJS where I switch players every two turns. This code works the first time but I would like to loop through the function to keep switching players. Here is my code:

```
app.controller('EventController', function($scope){

$scope.score1 = 0;
$scope.score2 = 0;
$scope.playing = true;
$scope.win1 = false;
$scope.lose1 = false;
$scope.win2 = false;
$scope.lose2 = false;

//Counter
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.totalScore = $scope.score1 + $scope.score2;

$scope.player1 = " Player 1";
$scope.player2 = " Player 2";

$scope.currentplayer = $scope.player1;



    $scope.switchplayer = function(){

        if ($scope.counter % 2 === 0){

            if($scope.totalScore % 2 === 0){
                $scope.currentplayer = $scope.player2;
            } else {
                $scope.currentplayer = $scope.player1;
            }

    }};



  $scope.incrementScore1 = function() {

    $scope.score1++;
    $scope.counter++;

    if ($scope.score1 === 11){

        $scope.playing = false;
        $scope.win1 = true;
        $scope.lose2 = true;
        console.log('Player 1 wins!');
    }
  };

  $scope.incrementScore2 = function() {

    $scope.score2++;
     $scope.counter++;
    if ($scope.score2 == 11){
        $scope.playing = false;
        $scope.win2 = true;
        $scope.lose1 = true;
        console.log('Player 2 wins!');
    }
  };

$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.score1='0';
    $scope.score2='0';
    $scope.playing = true;
    $scope.win1 = false;
    $scope.lose1 = false;
    $scope.win2 = false;
    $scope.lose2 = false;
};


});

<div class="container" ng-controller='EventController'>
    <h1>Score Keeper</h1>
    <h3>Current Serve:<span>{{currentplayer}}</span></h3>
    <div class="row" ng-class="{'current': playing}">


        <div class="col-md-6" ng-click='incrementScore1();switchplayer()' ng-model='score1' ng-class="{'win1': win1, 'lose1': lose1}">
            <p>{{score1}}</p><br><br><br>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6" ng-model='score2' ng-click='incrementScore2();switchplayer()' ng-class="{'win2': win2, 'lose2': lose2}">
        <p>{{score2}}</p><br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click='reset()'>Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error and explain the steps, along with the actual outcome and your expected outcome?

Comment: Hi, I set the initial currentplayer to player1. After the count is incremented by 2 it changes to player2 in my view. The problem is that it remains to player 2 after the first changes and never changes back to player1. Here is my view code. I am not getting any errors:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totalScore is never updated in your code, so the calculation with totalScore is not correct (it will always be 0). Just switch the player depending on what the current player is instead.

```
$scope.switchplayer = function(){

    if ($scope.counter % 2 === 0){
        $scope.currentplayer = $scope.currentplayer === $scope.player2
            ? $scope.player1
            : $scope.player2;

}};
```

And don't forget to reset counter in your reset function. Otherwise you may end up changing the player every odd turn instead.

```
$scope.counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just work with `% 4`:

```
    $scope.switchplayer = function(){
        if($scope.totalScore % 4 >= 2){
            $scope.currentplayer = $scope.player2;
        } else {
            $scope.currentplayer = $scope.player1;
        }
    };
```

So player1 is the currentplayer for `0` and `1` as remainder and player2 for `2` and `3` as remainder. After 4 loops it starts again from the beginning.

Comment: Does anything else need to be updated in the code. This seems to only change to player1 and is not changing.

Comment: As far as i can see, this is the only change. The totalScore is incraesed on every move.. So with a totalScore of 5 player1 would be the currentplayer again  and with 7 it would be player2... and so on.